# Ftp not working in passive mode in filezilla

Tags: ftp

When I try to connect to my server using passive mode in filezilla I get "421 3 users (the maximum) are already logged in, sorry" error I increased the maximum number of connections to 8 , even then I get the same error. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

> 421 3 users (the maximum) are already logged in, sorry"

This has nothing to do with passive or active mode, since you already fail to login and thus are not able to switch to passive or active mode for data connections.

> error I increased the maximum number of connections to 8 , even then I get the same error. How to solve this?

Make sure that the changed configuration are really active (server restart?). Make sure that you've changed the correct values. Look into the documentation and into the error log for your server for details. Don't expect any help for server configuration if you don't provide information about the server you use and anyway ask at serverfault.com for server side configuration.